# What should be give in URL Scheme and callback url in Square Connect

Tags: ios, objective-c, square-connect

I want to use square connect as payment gateway in my ios app.I confused what should be given in **Ios app Url scheme** in square connect website as well as in my **Info.plist file** and in my code too.

I had done in different type

```
NSURL *const callbackURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"your-url-scheme://myCallback"];
SCCMoney *const amount = [SCCMoney moneyWithAmountCents:100 currencyCode:@"USD" error:NULL];
[SCCAPIRequest setClientID:@"YOUR_CLIENT_ID"];
SCCAPIRequest *request = [
   SCCAPIRequest requestWithCallbackURL:callbackURL 
   amount:amount
   userInfoString:nil
   merchantID:nil
   notes:@"Coffee"
   customerID:nil
   supportedTenderTypes:SCCAPIRequestTenderTypeAll
   clearsDefaultFees:NO
   returnAutomaticallyAfterPayment:NO
   error:&error
];
```

What should be given in **Ios app Url scheme** as in the pic and **call back url** in the code?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can choose the url scheme for your application. If you look at the sample application's [info.plist](https://github.com/square/SquarePointOfSaleSDK-iOS/blob/master/HelloCharge/HelloCharge-Info.plist), they use `hellocharge`. You'll need to choose one to use for your application.

See also the [Square Point of Sale iOS guide](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/register-api-ios).

Comment: hi sir i did what you said but an alert is appearing  "cannot perform request.Ensure that "square-commerce-v1" is included in the LSApplicationqueriesSchemes in info.plist".I included  "square-commerce-v1"in the LSApplicationqueriesSchemes in info.plist why i am getting this?? please help me sir

Comment: Can you share the content of your info.plist?

Comment: Sorry sir I can't.Sir I have a doubt does square connect is having payment gateway(not POS) for IOS app like PayPal I found some links that Square doesn't have any plugins for mobile apps ..


These are the links I found:

https://docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/faq-ecommerce-cms

https://squareup.com/townsquare/payment-api

Comment: If you want to use Square for card not present transactions, you can use the payments APIs.

Comment: Client requested to include square payment either that might be Card or transactions, Can we achieve and include it in my Native iOS application .Can u provide me a link to work Square in web browser ..What information do u require from plist to rectify it i will provide u..